# Looking for a paper of A.bella in 1987

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Looking for a paper:

> Bella A. Remarks on the metrizability degree[J]. Boll. Un. Mat. Ital. A (7), 1987, 1(3): 391-396.

Could you help me?

Comment: I do not see why this has a close vote. Finding papers can be difficult, and asking here is a good idea.

Comment: (To answer the question, you could try e-mailing A. Bella? His e-mail address can be found on his [arXiv papers](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Bella_A/0/1/0/all/0/1).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The journal this citation is taken from is Unione Matematica Italiana. Bollettino. A.  The electronic text of this bulletin is not available online.  If you are based at Cambridge, Glasgow or Edinburgh Universities then you can find a copy in their University libraries.

If you go to [this link](http://www.worldcat.org/title/bollettino-della-unione-matematica-italiana-a/oclc/2973154) you can find the closest library to you that has a copy.

Otherwise, it's on Google books at http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Bollettino_della_Unione_matematica_itali.html?id=LcTxAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y , which might give you more information on how you might get a copy.